# Dynamic Table from PHP Array

Tags: php, dynamic

I am trying to display a multidimension php array as a table... can someone help?

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => UA07
                    [s1] => 6
                    [c2] => Ultimate Force
                    [s2] => 8
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => UF HEROES
                    [s1] => 6
                    [c2] => OLD School
                    [s2] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => Winners 05 
                    [s1] => not_played
                    [c2] => World XI
                    [s2] => not_played
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => Outlaw
                    [s1] => 4
                    [c2] => UWK
                    [s2] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => Ultimate Force
                    [s1] => 2
                    [c2] => UF HEROES
                    [s2] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => BY
                    [s1] => 0
                    [c2] => Outlaw
                    [s2] => 0
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [c1] => UF HEROES
                    [s1] => 5
                    [c2] => Outlaw
                    [s2] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

This array currently contains 3 rounds, but could in theory contain more... and within each round it contains each game, and within each game it contains the results of those games...

C1/C2 are competitors and S1 / S2 are the scores...

How do I display each array in a column and move on to the next array and show them in columns as well.. lining them up like a tournament bracket

Any thoughts would be very helpful.

I am trying to achieve a format like this:

http://new.playdat.com/tournament-results.php "Bracket"

Comment: So use a nested loop? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Indeed, nested loops and properly formatted HTML would do it, but that seems to be a lot of data to display on the same page, you might want to use a different approach regarding user-friendlyness

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, you need a nested loop. Since you didn't specify a table format, I just created an example. You can run this at http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
/** Simulating your data **/
$rounds = array();
$rounds[1][] = array('c1' => 'UA07', 's1' => 6, 'c2' => 'Ultimate Force', 's2' => 8); 
$rounds[1][] = array('c1' => 'UF HEROES', 's1' => 6, 'c2' => 'Old School', 's2' => 4); 
$rounds[2][] = array('c1' => 'Ultimate Force', 's1' => 2, 'c2' => 'UF HEROES', 's2' => 4); 
$rounds[2][] = array('c1' => 'BY', 's1' => 0, 'c2' => 'Outlaw', 's2' => 0); 


$table = <<<EOD

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Round</th>
                    <th>C1</th>
                    <th>S1</th>
                    <th>C2</th>
                    <th>S2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
EOD;

foreach ($rounds as $roundNum=> $round){

    foreach ($round as $game) {

        $table .= "<tr>";
        $table .= "<td>{$roundNum}</td>";
        $table .= "<td>{$game['c1']}</td>";
        $table .= "<td>{$game['s1']}</td>";
        $table .= "<td>{$game['c2']}</td>";
        $table .= "<td>{$game['s1']}</td>";
        $table .= "</tr>";


    }
}

$table .= <<<EOD
            </tbody>
        </table>
EOD;

echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic tournament bracket:

Your array:

```
$rounds = array(
    //Round 1
    array(

        array(
            'c1' => 'UA07 ',
            's1' => 6 ,
            'c2' => 'Ultimate Force ',
            's2' => 8 ,
        ),

        array(
            'c1' => 'UF HEROES',
            's1' => 6,
            'c2' => 'OLD School',
            's2' => 4,
        ),

        array(
                'c1' => 'Winners 05 ',
                's1' => 'not_played',
                'c2' => 'World XI',
                's2' => 'not_played',
        ),

        array(
                'c1' => 'Outlaw',
                's1' => 4,
                'c2' => 'UWK',
                's2' => 3,
        ),

    ),
    //Round 2
    array(
       array(
                'c1' => 'Ultimate Force',
                's1' => 2,
                'c2' => 'UF HEROES',
                's2' => 4,
        ),

        array(
                'c1' => 'BY',
                's1' => 0,
                'c2' => 'Outlaw',
                's2' => 0,
        ),

    ),
    //Round 3
    array(
        array(
                'c1' => 'UF HEROES',
                's1' => 5,
                'c2' => 'Outlaw',
                's2' => 1,
        ),

    )
);
```

The generator:

```
$roundCount = 1;
$totalRounds = count($rounds);

echo '<table border="1"><tr>';

for($i = 1;$i <= $totalRounds;$i++)
{
    echo '<td>Round'.$i.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr><tr>';
foreach($rounds as $round)
{
    $matches = count($round);
    echo '<td>';


    foreach($round as $match)
    {

        echo $match['c1'].' - '.$match['s1'].'<br>';
        echo $match['c2'].' - '.$match['s2'].'<br><hr>';

    }
    $roundCount++;
    echo '</td>';
}

echo '</tr></table>';
```

Results:

[image: tournament bracket]
Generator 2:

```
$roundCount = 1;
$totalRounds = count($rounds);

echo '<table border="1"><tr>';

for($i = 1;$i <= $totalRounds;$i++)
{
    echo '<td>Round'.$i.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr><tr>';
foreach($rounds as $round)
{
    $matches = count($round);
    echo '<td>';


    foreach($round as $match)
    {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$match['c1'].'</td><td>'.$match['s1'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$match['c2'].'</td><td>'.$match['s2'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
    $roundCount++;
    echo '</td>';
}

echo '</tr></table>';
```

Generator with winner:

```
$roundCount = 1;
$totalRounds = count($rounds);

echo '<table border="1"><tr>';

for($i = 1;$i <= $totalRounds;$i++)
{
    echo '<td>Round'.$i.'</td>';
}
echo '<td>Winner</td>';
echo '</tr><tr>';
foreach($rounds as $round)
{
    $matches = count($round);
    echo '<td>';

    if($roundCount == $totalRounds)
    {
        if($round[0]['s1'] > $round[0]['s2']) {
            $finalist = array($round[0]['c1'],$round[0]['s1']);
        } else {
            $finalist = array($round[0]['c2'],$round[0]['s2']);
        }
    }

    foreach($round as $match)
    {
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$match['c1'].'</td><td>'.$match['s1'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>'.$match['c2'].'</td><td>'.$match['s2'].'</td></tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
    $roundCount++;

    echo '</td>';
}
echo '<td>';

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><td>'.$finalist[0].'</td><td>'.$finalist[1].'</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';

echo '</td>';

echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: Thank you... I just could not get my head around it... we were doing it manually before, but that was becoming cumbersome. We have some special cases where the round could be 0, but we can deal with that... it is just a case now of nicely formatting the table so the results line up like a tournament bracket would.. thanks again

Comment: Actually, this does not quite work and I am unsure how to solve...

Each of the team names and scores should be in their own cells.. so that we can format it all nicely...

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Hello.

I am finally finishing off the implementation of this code and having some issues... perhaps you can help.

When my array is returned it gives me all the game results, it also gives me the winning team name... how do I add this team name to the final column in the above code.. I have tried a few things and it seems to end up everywhere but where I want it.

Also, how do I space the columns so that the team names line up as they would in a tournament bracket? 

Thanks

Comment: @Staggan See my last example. I don't understand "space the columns so that the team names line up "

Comment: Hello.

I have amended my original post and given a link to what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: I had another thought actually.

We currently have a function which uses GD Lib to produce an image which shows our results correctly... would it be possible instead to duplicate the CSS look using GD Lib?

Comment: Sorry but this is too much formatting for me. I do backend php.